# OpenGL not drawing lines/text?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm creating a tic tac toe game in open gl Im not finished yet but whenever I run my code all I see is a black screen I do not see the lines that I have drawn or the X?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <GLut/glut.h>

using namespace std;

int matrix[ 3 ][ 3 ]; // board for the gameplay of tic tac toe we are using a 3x3 matrix board
int turn; // indicates whose turn it is going to be
bool gameover; // is the game over would you like to end the game
int result; // the ending result of the game

void begin()
{
    turn = 1;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) // setting up the board and clearing the matrix we start at 1,
                                 // basically clearing our matrix
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            matrix[ i ][ j ] = 0;
    }
}

void drawxo() // setting up our X and O if it is 1 then we want to use x and if it is 2 then 0
{
    for( int i = 0; i <= 2; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j <= 2; j++ )
        {
            if( matrix[ i ][ j ] == 1 ) // if it is 1 then draw x
            {
                glBegin( GL_LINES );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glEnd();
            }
            else if( matrix[ i ][ j ] == 2 ) // if it is 2 then draw o
            {
                glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}

void DrawString( void* font, const char s[], float x, float y )
{
    unsigned int i;
    glRasterPos2f( x, y );
    for( i = 0; i < strlen( s ); i++ )
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter( font, s[ i ] );
    }
}

void drawLines()
{
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 0 );
    // 2 vertical lines
    glVertex2f( 100, 50 );
    glVertex2f( 100, 340 );
    glVertex2f( 200, 340 );
    glVertex2f( 200, 50 );
    // 2 horizontal lines
    glVertex2f( 0, 150 );
    glVertex2f( 300, 150 );
    glVertex2f( 0, 250 );
    glVertex2f( 300, 250 );
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
    glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 0 );
    if( turn == 1 )
        DrawString( GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "Player1's turn", 100, 30 );

    drawxo();
    drawLines();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void KeyPress( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch( key )
    {
    case 27: // the escape key to exit the program
        exit( 0 );
        break;
    case 'y':
        if( gameover = true )
        {
            gameover = false;
            begin();
        }
        break;
    case 'n':
        if( gameover = true )
        {
            exit( 0 );
        }
        break;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    begin();
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowPosition( 550, 200 );
    glutInitWindowSize( 300, 350 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Tic tac toe" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( KeyPress );
    glutIdleFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the default identity projection & modelview matrices results in in a  (±1,  ±1,  ±1) clipping volume which all your geometry is outside.  Either fix your geometry to fit within the clip volume or adjust the clip volume to encompass your geometry.

Since all your drawing code seems to be assuming a 300x350 inverted-Y coordinate system you can set an appropriate `GL_PROJECTION` matrix via [`glOrtho()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glOrtho.xml):

```
void display()
{
    glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // new
    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, 300, 0, 350, -1, 1 );

    // new
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    ...
```

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

All together:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>
#include <GL/glut.h>

using namespace std;

int matrix[ 3 ][ 3 ]; // board for the gameplay of tic tac toe we are using a 3x3 matrix board
int turn; // indicates whose turn it is going to be
bool gameover; // is the game over would you like to end the game
int result; // the ending result of the game

void begin()
{
    turn = 1;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) // setting up the board and clearing the matrix we start at 1,
                                 // basically clearing our matrix
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < 3; j++ )
            matrix[ i ][ j ] = 0;
    }
}

void drawxo() // setting up our X and O if it is 1 then we want to use x and if it is 2 then 0
{
    for( int i = 0; i <= 2; i++ )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j <= 2; j++ )
        {
            if( matrix[ i ][ j ] == 1 ) // if it is 1 then draw x
            {
                glBegin( GL_LINES );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glEnd();
            }
            else if( matrix[ i ][ j ] == 2 ) // if it is 2 then draw o
            {
                glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 - 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 + 25 );
                glVertex2f( 50 + j * 100 + 25, 100 + i * 100 - 25 );
                glEnd();
            }
        }
    }
}

void DrawString( void* font, const char s[], float x, float y )
{
    unsigned int i;
    glRasterPos2f( x, y );
    for( i = 0; i < strlen( s ); i++ )
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter( font, s[ i ] );
    }
}

void drawLines()
{
    glBegin( GL_LINES );
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 0 );
    // 2 vertical lines
    glVertex2f( 100, 50 );
    glVertex2f( 100, 340 );
    glVertex2f( 200, 340 );
    glVertex2f( 200, 50 );
    // 2 horizontal lines
    glVertex2f( 0, 150 );
    glVertex2f( 300, 150 );
    glVertex2f( 0, 250 );
    glVertex2f( 300, 250 );
    glEnd();
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor( 1, 1, 1, 1 );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho( 0, 300, 0, 350, -1, 1 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3f( 0, 0, 0 );
    if( turn == 1 )
        DrawString( GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18, "Player1's turn", 100, 30 );

    drawxo();
    drawLines();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void KeyPress( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
    switch( key )
    {
    case 27: // the escape key to exit the program
        exit( 0 );
        break;
    case 'y':
        if( gameover = true )
        {
            gameover = false;
            begin();
        }
        break;
    case 'n':
        if( gameover = true )
        {
            exit( 0 );
        }
        break;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    begin();
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutInitWindowSize( 300, 350 );
    glutCreateWindow( "Tic tac toe" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    glutKeyboardFunc( KeyPress );
    glutIdleFunc( display );
    glutMainLoop();
}
```